# Why do these rules have this behaviour in Odoo 11?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-11

As always, problems with rules. I thought I had finally understood them, but not.

I am looking the behaviour of model accesses and rules in the module `hr_attendance` of Odoo 11.

**THE CODE**

They create three groups:

- `group_hr_attendance` (*Manual Attendance*).
- `group_hr_attendance_user` (*Officer*): belonging to this group implies belonging to `group_hr_attendance`.
- `group_hr_attendance_manager` (*Manager*): belonging to this group implies belonging to `group_hr_attendance_user`.

They give the following model accesses to the groups:

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_hr_attendance_user,hr.attendance.user,model_hr_attendance,hr_attendance.group_hr_attendance_user,1,1,1,1
access_hr_attendance_system_user,hr.attendance.system.user,model_hr_attendance,base.group_user,1,1,1,0
```

They are setting accesses to *Officer* and the basic group *Employee*.

And they apply the following rules:

```
 <record id="hr_attendance_rule_attendance_manager" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">attendance officer: full access</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_hr_attendance"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[(1,'=',1)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('hr_attendance.group_hr_attendance_user'))]"/>
</record>

<record id="hr_attendance_rule_attendance_employee" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">user: modify own attendance only</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_hr_attendance"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('employee_id.user_id','=',user.id)]</field>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="0"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="1"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="1"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="0"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
</record>
```

**THE BEHAVIOUR**

If I log in with a basic user who belongs to the *Manual Attendance* group, I can see attendances whose employee's users are not mine, and if I open and try to modify them, I get a security error: *(Document type: Attendance, Operation: write)*.

**HOW I THINK THIS CASE WORKED**

My user belong to *Manual Attendance* group: it does not have model accesses so I have the CRUD 0 0 0 0 (I cannot create, read, update or delete any record of the `hr_attendance` model). But my user (as everyone) also belongs to *Employee* group, so I also have the CRUD 1 1 1 0. As model accesses are additive, I can create, read and update any record of `hr_attendance` model, but not delete.

After that, the rules are restricting the CRUD. The non-global rule `hr_attendance_rule_attendance_employee` (*user: modify own attendance only*) is affecting to my user: supposedly, the records which match the domain will be accessible for my group. The other ones will not. So I will not be able to interact with attendances whose employee's user is not mine. And I have two doubts here:

- Why the rule has a 0 in read? Isn't that destroying my read permission given by the model accesses? I thought global or non-global rules were restrictive against model accesses.
- And why I can read records whose employee's user is not mine? They do not match the rule so I should not be able to see them, shouldn't I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstanding the record rule `perm_*`, are used to make the record rule applicable or the opposite.

### Your questions:

- **Q:** Why the rule has a 0 in read? Isn't that destroying my read permission given by the model accesses?
- **A**: The read value set to 0 to make sure this rule is not evaluated when the user make a read request. And you are not destroying your read permission given by the model access, if the read value was set to 1, you can say that you are narrowing the model access permission,  from the whole model to the records those only passed the forced domain.
- **Q:** And why I can read records whose employee's user is not mine? They does not match the rule so I should not be able to see them, shouldn't I?
- **A**: **According to your model access, both groups have read access, and there are no record rules limiting read access.

  ## HOW!? WHY!!!?

  1. The first rule `hr_attendance_rule_attendance_manager`, is evaluated on the `read`, `write`, `create` and `unlink` access to the group `hr_attendance.group_hr_attendance_user`. (No explicit evaluation peams provided, by default set to 1)
  2. The second rule `hr_attendance_rule_attendance_employee` is evaluated on the `write` and `create` access only (perm_write=1 and perm_create=1), and not evaluated on the `read` and `unlink` access (perm_read=0 and perm_unlink=0).

### So

You should be able to unlink also :). To get the result that you want, you need to set the `perm_read` to 1, and to force the domain on the unlink access you need to set the `perm_unlink` also to 1.

## Note

you may use separate rules for each access request (read, write, create and unlink) when you have complex access conditions.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much @Omer, great explanation! Only one doubt about your answer: you say that *You should be able to unlink also :)*, but if the rule has a 0 in *perm_unlink*, I've understood that the rule is ignored when removing records, so the model access will be taken into account and it has a 0 in delete, so I shouldn't be able to delete, should I? I mean, if model access sets 0 for a permission, rules never can set it to 1, am I right?

Comment: Yes! you all right. I'v missed about the access model at this point, I assumed wrongly it was set to 1. if it was set to 1 you should be able to unlink.